# Wordpress menu - <ul> with additional data

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, apostrophe

Hello i have problem with apostrophe when i want to add this in wordpress menu:

**data-uk-scrollspy-nav="{closest:'li', smoothscroll:true}"**

i want to menu looks like that:

```
   <ul class="uk-subnav" data-uk-scrollspy-nav="{closest:'li', smoothscroll:true}">
        <li class="uk-active"><a href="#getstarted">Get Started</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#templatesettings">Template Settings</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#customizer">Customizer</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#customization">Customizaton</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#troubleshooting">Troubleshooting</a></li>                               
    </ul>
```

so my wordpress code for it is:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'menu_class' => 'uk-navbar-nav uk-hidden-small',
        'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
        'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" data-uk-scrollspy-nav="{closest:"li", smoothscroll:true}" >%3$s</ul>'
    )
); ?>
```

but i have this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'li' (T_STRING), expecting ')'
>   in /themes/dev/index.php on line 41

so the problem is apostrophe but i cant put quotation mark becouse script dont work.

anyone know how to resolve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the single quotes but escape them like so:

```
 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" data-uk-scrollspy-nav="{closest:\'li\', smoothscroll:true}" >%3$s</ul>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not working

I found another solution

```
$x="closest:'li'";
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'menu_class' => 'uk-navbar-nav uk-hidden-small',
        'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
        'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" data-uk-scrollspy-nav="{'.$x.', smoothscroll:true}" >%3$s</ul>'
    )
```